# Automation Studio with Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I tried to create an Automation Studio with a journey and when I placed an audience the option did not work out anymore. Can someone please tell me how it is done now?

[image: I mean this]

How can I create a journey and use it in an automation studio?

[image: I want to see it in automation studio in this way]

and Is it possible to execute a second journey after the first journey is completed automatically with automation studio?

thanks

Comment: Can you please add more details. For instance what do you mean by 'tried to create an Automation Studio with a journey'? And please explain what you mean by 'did not work anymore'. Did it error? Incorrect information? The more detail you provide, the more effective our help will be.

Comment: Ok. update question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This option has now been moved to the schedule options when creating a Data Extension Entry Event Journey. The automation entry is now no longer its own entry event.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_schedule_a_data_extension_entry_source.htm&type=5

2. There is not an option for a second Journey to be automatically kicked off from automation studio when the first Journey completes. You could however use the update contact activity from within the first Journey to add records to a data extension to then use in a separate Journey.